# Println printing multiple times instead of increasing for each loop

Tags: java, count, println, accumulate

I'm trying to make this code print out the number of games played (`gameNum`). Instead, it always sets `gameNum` to `2`, and prints out the last println the number of times that the game was played. I feel like I made a dumb mistake here, but I am having trouble finding it. Could you please give me a hint instead of the answer? I'd like to figure this out on my own. If not, then feel free to go ahead and write the answer.

Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Testing_gameNum {
    public static final int amt = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        guessCounter(console);
    }

    public static int game(Scanner console) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int guess = 0;
        int guessNum = 0;
        System.out.printf("I'm thinking of a number...", amt);
        System.out.println();
        int num = 1;

        do {
            System.out.println("Your guess? ");
            guess = console.nextInt();
            guessNum += guessNum;
        } while (guess != num);

        return guessNum;
    }

    public static void guessCounter(Scanner console) {
        int gameNum = 1;
        int guessNum = game(console);
        if (guessNum == 1){
            System.out.printf("You won in %d guesses!", guessNum);
            System.out.println();
        }
        gameNum = gameNum + 1;
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
        String play = console.next();
        if (play.equals("y")) {
            guessCounter(console);
        }
        System.out.println("Number of games: " + gameNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I'd like to figure this out on my own". Try to add `print` statements showing values at several points, thus validating your assumptions. Also, if you use an IDE, learn to use its debugger to step through the program and inspect variable values.

Comment: Look at the condition(s) that might make your gameNum change.  Do they never fire, sometimes fire or always fire?

Comment: `guessCounter` sets `gameNum` to `1` (and then increments it to `2`) each time it's called. You need to take it out of the function or not override it each time.

Comment: Think about what happens when you recurse in `guessCounter`. Consider using a loop.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I'm posting an answer with the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class Testing_gameNum
{
   public static final int amt = 1;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      guessCounter(console);
   }

   public static int game(Scanner console)
   {
      Random rand = new Random();
      int guess = 0;
      int guessNum = 0;
      System.out.printf("I'm thinking of a number...", amt);
      System.out.println();
      int num = 1;
      do
      {
         System.out.println("Your guess? ");
         guess = console.nextInt();
         guessNum += amt;
      }
      while (guess != num);
      return guessNum;
   }
   public static void guessCounter(Scanner console)
   {
      int gameNum = 1;
      do
      {
         int guessNum = game(console);
         if (guessNum == 1)
         {
            System.out.printf("You won in %d guesses!", guessNum);
            System.out.println();
         }
         gameNum = gameNum + 1;
         System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
         String play = console.next();
      }
      while (play.equals("y"))
      System.out.println("Number of games: " + gameNum);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check for every place `gameNum` is used. I found it i.e. in the method `guessCounter(Scanner console)` - and only there.
- So every time you call this method, the value of `gameNum` is initialized to 1. After the game is won, you increment it by 1 and later on print it, hence the 2 in the output.
- Move `int gameNum = 1;` out of the method  `guessCounter(Scanner console)`. This should help.

Aside of this please review also the code block

```
if (play.equals("y")) {
  guessCounter(console);
}
```

Imagine a player goes on and on, always selecting "y". With every game round, you create another level of recursion. This "do you want to play again" could be implemented by a do-while loop, this will avoid the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `guessCounter` to be a recursive method, but that's probably not what you want for several reasons.  First, each time you call `guessCounter`, you're creating a new `gameNum` and setting it to `1`.  You play the game and increment it to `2`, but then recurse and never touch that variable again, which is the cause of your bug.  Additionally, (although this is unlikely to happen in usual play), you could overflow your stack if you play the game enough times.  Each time you play the game, the computer needs to remember the point in code that it needs to return to when it completes that call of `guessCounter`.  Eventually you will run out of memory to store those pointers.  Recursion is good for certain problems, but it's better to use loops most of the time.

How about using a loop rather than recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question! Here's the code (explanation below):

```
public class Testing_gameNum {
    public static final int amt = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        guessCounter(console);
    }

    public static int game(Scanner console) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int guess = 0;
        int guessNum = 0;
        System.out.printf("I'm thinking of a number...", amt);
        System.out.println();
        int num = 1;

        do {
            System.out.println("Your guess? ");
            guess = console.nextInt();
            guessNum ++;
        } while (guess != num);

        return guessNum;
    }

    public static void guessCounter(Scanner console) {
        int gameNum = 0;
        String play = "y";
            do {
                int guessNum = game(console);
                gameNum += 1;
                if (guessNum == 1) {
                    System.out.printf("You won in %d guesses!", guessNum);
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
                play = console.next();
            } while (play.equals("y"));
        System.out.println("Number of games: " + gameNum);
    }
}
```

MY PROBLEMS: `gameNum` was resetting each time I called `guessCounter`. I needed a `do/while` loop; that way, I could initialize `gameNum` inside the method, and then loop only the section of the method that needed to be repeated. The repetitive `println` was linked with that same issue: it was reprinted each time I called `guessCounter`, as opposed to just the part of the code I wanted repeated.

Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: Please upvote the answers that helped you to resolve your problem.

Comment: I don't yet have enough reputation. I will upvote answers once I get to that point.